# Issue in generating jssecacerts in java

Tags: java, ssl, ldap, jsse, unboundid-ldap-sdk

Apologies if this is seems to be duplicate question, My concern here is -  i have verified all the post even though i am unable to generate the jssecacerts file.

Here is my code for generating the jssecacerts ,

```
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

/**
 * Class used to add the server's certificate to the KeyStore
 * with your trusted certificates.
 */
public class SSLCertGen {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String host;
    int port;
    char[] passphrase;
    if ((args.length == 1) || (args.length == 2)) {
        String[] c = args[0].split(":");
        host = c[0];
        port = (c.length == 1) ? 443 : Integer.parseInt(c[1]);
        String p = (args.length == 1) ? "changeit" : args[1];
        passphrase = p.toCharArray();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Usage: java InstallCert [:port] [passphrase]");
        return;
    }

    File file = new File("jssecacerts");
    if (file.isFile() == false) {
        char SEP = File.separatorChar;
        File dir = new File(System.getProperty("java.home") + SEP
                + "lib" + SEP + "security");
        file = new File(dir, "jssecacerts");
        if (file.isFile() == false) {
            file = new File(dir, "cacerts");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Loading KeyStore " + file + "...");
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(in, passphrase);
    in.close();

    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    TrustManagerFactory tmf =
            TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(ks);
    X509TrustManager defaultTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
    SavingTrustManager tm = new SavingTrustManager(defaultTrustManager);
    context.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
    SSLSocketFactory factory = context.getSocketFactory();

    System.out.println("Opening connection to " + host + ":" + port + "...");
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port);
    socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
    try {
        System.out.println("Starting SSL handshake...");
        socket.startHandshake();
        socket.close();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("No errors, certificate is already trusted");
    } catch (SSLException e) {
        System.out.println();
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

    X509Certificate[] chain = tm.chain;
    if (chain == null) {
        System.out.println("Could not obtain server certificate chain");
        return;
    }

    BufferedReader reader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Server sent " + chain.length + " certificate(s):");
    System.out.println();
    MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    for (int i = 0; i < chain.length; i++) {
        X509Certificate cert = chain[i];
        System.out.println
                (" " + (i + 1) + " Subject " + cert.getSubjectDN());
        System.out.println("   Issuer  " + cert.getIssuerDN());
        sha1.update(cert.getEncoded());
        System.out.println("   sha1    " + toHexString(sha1.digest()));
        md5.update(cert.getEncoded());
        System.out.println("   md5     " + toHexString(md5.digest()));
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("Enter certificate to add to trusted keystore or 'q' to quit: [1]");
    String line = reader.readLine().trim();
    int k;
    try {
        k = (line.length() == 0) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(line) - 1;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("KeyStore not changed");
        return;
    }

    X509Certificate cert = chain[k];
    String alias = host + "-" + (k + 1);
    ks.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("jssecacerts");
    ks.store(out, passphrase);
    out.close();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(cert);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println
            ("Added certificate to keystore 'jssecacerts' using alias '"
                    + alias + "'");
}

private static final char[] HEXDIGITS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();

private static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 3);
    for (int b : bytes) {
        b &= 0xff;
        sb.append(HEXDIGITS[b >> 4]);
        sb.append(HEXDIGITS[b & 15]);
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private static class SavingTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    private final X509TrustManager tm;
    private X509Certificate[] chain;

    SavingTrustManager(X509TrustManager tm) {
        this.tm = tm;
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {

    /** 
     * This change has been done due to the following resolution advised for Java 1.7+
    http://infposs.blogspot.kr/2013/06/installcert-and-java-7.html
         **/ 

    return new X509Certificate[0];  
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
            throws CertificateException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
            throws CertificateException {
        this.chain = chain;
        tm.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
    }
}
}
```

I ran the above class with command line argument in eclipse

[image]

While executing it throws a below exception,

```
 Loading KeyStore C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts...
Opening connection to 192.168.200.1:636...
Starting SSL handshake...

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at SSLCertGen.main(SSLCertGen.java:98)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
Could not obtain server certificate chain
```

Could you let me whether i have missed any or doing in a wrong way.

Addtional debugging(-Djavax.net.debug=all) inputs here,

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Opening connection to 192.168.200.1:636...
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(10000) called
Starting SSL handshake...
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1423236433 bytes = { 97, 95, 194, 109, 223, 52, 36, 48, 215, 195, 28, 99, 190, 58, 171, 173, 231, 51, 45, 245, 235, 71, 137, 149, 122, 243, 5, 30 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 149
0000: 01 00 00 91 03 01 55 D5   DD 51 61 5F C2 6D DF 34  ......U..Qa_.m.4
0010: 24 30 D7 C3 1C 63 BE 3A   AB AD E7 33 2D F5 EB 47  $0...c.:...3-..G
0020: 89 95 7A F3 05 1E 00 00   2A C0 09 C0 13 00 2F C0  ..z.....*...../.
0030: 04 C0 0E 00 33 00 32 C0   07 C0 11 00 05 C0 02 C0  ....3.2.........
0040: 0C C0 08 C0 12 00 0A C0   03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13 00  ................
0050: 04 00 FF 01 00 00 3E 00   0A 00 34 00 32 00 17 00  ......>...4.2...
0060: 01 00 03 00 13 00 15 00   06 00 07 00 09 00 0A 00  ................
0070: 18 00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00   0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00  ................
0080: 11 00 02 00 12 00 04 00   05 00 14 00 08 00 16 00  ................
0090: 0B 00 02 01 00                                     .....
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 149
[Raw write]: length = 154
0000: 16 03 01 00 95 01 00 00   91 03 01 55 D5 DD 51 61  ...........U..Qa
0010: 5F C2 6D DF 34 24 30 D7   C3 1C 63 BE 3A AB AD E7  _.m.4$0...c.:...
0020: 33 2D F5 EB 47 89 95 7A   F3 05 1E 00 00 2A C0 09  3-..G..z.....*..
0030: C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0 0E   00 33 00 32 C0 07 C0 11  .../.....3.2....
0040: 00 05 C0 02 C0 0C C0 08   C0 12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D  ................
0050: 00 16 00 13 00 04 00 FF   01 00 00 3E 00 0A 00 34  ...........>...4
0060: 00 32 00 17 00 01 00 03   00 13 00 15 00 06 00 07  .2..............
0070: 00 09 00 0A 00 18 00 0B   00 0C 00 19 00 0D 00 0E  ................
0080: 00 0F 00 10 00 11 00 02   00 12 00 04 00 05 00 14  ................
0090: 00 08 00 16 00 0B 00 02   01 00                    ..........
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
main, called closeSocket()
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at SSLCertGen.main(SSLCertGen.java:98)
```

Answer (score 0):

After wasting a complete day i have found my mistake..

In order to make a SSL handshake - we need to install a SSL certificate in server end first

I had installed and everything works fine now